# For what values of $b$ is this quadratic form indefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I'm trying to determine what (real) values of $b$ the quadratic form $q = bx_1^2 + 2bx_2^2 + (9b + 2)x_3^2 − 2bx_1x_2 − 6bx_1x_3 + 4bx_2x_3$.

I know (using leading principal of minors) that the quadratic form is positive definite for $b \in (0,2)$ and positive semi-definite for $b \in [0,2]$ and that it cannot be negative definite/semi-definite for any real values of $b$. Thus this would indicate that it's indefinite for $b \in \mathbb R \text{\\} [0,2]$, however I am told that the answer is $b \in \mathbb R$. I can't see why this is correct as the quadratic form will be positive definite for $b \in (0,2) \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: When you say “the answer is $b\in\mathbb{R}$ do you mean its _in_definite for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes. @DavidM.  That's why I'm not sure if it's correct since I know the matrix is positive definite for the given interval.

Comment: Also note that for $b=0$, $q$ reduces to $2x_3^2$ which is clearly not indefinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadratic form corresponds to the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b&-b&-3b\\
-b&2b&2b\\
-3b&2b&9b+2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Computing the eigenvalues of this matrix for $b=1$ gives 
$$
\lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
12.2992\\
1.65159\\
0.049229
\end{bmatrix}
$$
*i.e.* the quadratic form is positive definite, whereas for $b=3$ we get
$$
\lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
33.4129\\
4.64512\\
-0.0579871
\end{bmatrix}
$$
*i.e.* the quadratic form is indefinite.

I think your answer is correct.

Comment: $$   b (x-y-3z)^2 + b (y-z)^2 + (2-b)z^2 $$  where $x=x_1, y=x_2, z=x_3$